# Xsession: .xsessionrc is not executed in Ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, bash, xserver

I have .xsessionrc for fixing Ubuntu's mouse acceleration issue.

I have been running Ubuntu 16 for a while and `~/.xsessionrc` started on login properly on but recently it stopped doing it.

Nothing unusual happened except I added ntfs partitions to `/etc/fstab` and started computer when they were hibernated, so I needed to run execute fsck from recovery mode.

File content:

```
xset m 1/2 16
xinput --set-prop "USB OPTICAL MOUSE " "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 1
```

If I start it manually from the terminal, mouse acceleration decreases, but it doesn't start automatically on logging on.

The `~/.xsessionrc` has 755 permissions if it matters. I have also tried adding these options to `/etc/rc.local` and `~/.bashrc`, but this has no effect.

I suppose the problem is with X session. So how can I fix it? Where can I read logs and investigate why the problem appears?

Thank you in advance.

*EDIT:*

Because I have the content of .xsessionrc file in `.bashrc`, the sensitivity decreases when I start the terminal.